# File.getUsableSpace() does not return the same value as the "df" command in Linux

Tags: java, linux

I want to print the number of bytes of all free space of a partition using `File.getUsuableSpace()` but it returns another value than the **df** command (in Linux) does.

It does not differ that much, but it differs in several megabytes.

What could be the case?

Comment: Is the result of **df** rounded to 1K block?

Comment: Yes, it is 1K block. But even if I divide File.getUsableSpace() by 1024, it differs.

Comment: Nothing should affect the hardrive between the execution of the java program and the "df" command. But maybe the OS or something does affect it?

Comment: Can you provide a small example of your results and the exact df syntax you use? Just in case...

Answer (score 2):

Is the file that your File instance represents on the same partition as the one you're running df on?

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getUsableSpace%28%29): "Returns the number of bytes available to this virtual machine on the **partition** named by this abstract pathname"

Emphasis is mine.

Comment: Yes, it is on the same partition. "df" lists all partitions.

Answer (score 0):

This will only give the available space, try `getFreeSpace()` will return the free space and not available to use space.  This works in Java 1.6, for more information, look at the [File class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getFreeSpace%28%29).